# organising gists by topic

Tags: github, gist, github-organizations

I've got a growing number of gists that I intend to use as a reference - however without the ability to organize them, I can foresee difficulty finding the right gist in the future.

Is there a way of organizing gists by topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GistBox](https://app.gistboxapp.com) where you can see all your gists and assign labels to them :

[image]

You can also search gist by label and keyword